# MVC Web API route config - filter controllers in route templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api-routing

My WebApiConfig.cs Register method looks like this:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "ClassroomContentApi",
        routeTemplate: "classroomContent/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional}
        );

    // Default
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional});

    MediaTypeHeaderValue appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
    config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
}
```

My `Controllers` folder in my MVC project is structured like this (these are not the real names of the controllers but that's not important):

```
Controllers
    ClassroomContent
        ClassroomController.cs
        ClassroomController2.cs
        ClassroomController3.cs
    SchoolInfo
        CampusController.cs
        CampusController2.cs
        CampusController3.cs
    StudentInfo
        StudentController.cs
        StudentController2.cs
        StudentController3.cs
    etc...
```

I want all the controllers in the `ClassroomContent` folder to use the first route above, and all the other controllers (in any other folders) to use the second route above.

The issue I am having is that the first route above picks up web api actions in controllers outside the `ClassroomContent` controllers folder, and vice versa.

For example, I can access `http://MYHOST/classroomContent/Campus` or `http://MYHOST/api/Classroom`. I want to be able to access the `Classroom` controller only from `http://MYHOST/classroomContent/Classroom` and the `Campus` controller only from `http://MYHOST/api/Campus`.

I understand that this is "expected behavior" in that nothing is preventing this from the perspective of how my routes are configured. But how do I prevent it?

What I have considered:

- Using areas. However, from what I read, they are not supported for Web API (at least not out of the box). I could try to explore the option of trying to implement areas functionality, but it seems like a lot when I am not even sure that they are the right solution.
- Defining a separate route for each controller. However, I have many controllers, so this seems very cumbersome.

What would be the best way to approach this problem? Is there any way to do it without trying to implement areas for Web API myself? Ideally I'd be able to somehow "filter" which controllers are valid values for the `{controller}` parameter of each route template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link should help you : http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Attribute%20routing%20in%20Web%20API

You can define custom routes at controller level with Web Api 2.

Answer (score 4):

[RouteConstraints](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs) should also work if you prefer not to use attribute routing.

Assuming your controllers are named: ClassRoom1Controller, ClassRoom2Controller etc the following should work (note that you can use regular expressions to configure the constraints so there should be many possibilities to configure this as you like):

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "ClassroomContentApi",
      routeTemplate: "classroomContent/{controller}/{id}",
      defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional},
      constraints: new { controller = "classRoom1|classRoom2|classRoom3" }
    );

// Default
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional},
    constraints: new { controller = @"^((?!(classRoom1|classRoom2|classRoom3)).)*$" });

MediaTypeHeaderValue appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
```

}

Comment: Thank you! If I could mark 2 answers as "accepted", I would. Yours is a great approach and answers my question very well with an example. However in my case the attribute routing works better. I upvoted both answers. :)